# how selenium select the option from dropdown list when there have no options

Tags: python, selenium, drop-down-menu

i am trying to use python+selenium to get the dropdown list options, but I found there have no options in the source code and the elements. so I do see the options from my browser, like this 
[image]

but when I inspect it, i only found this
[image]

I just want selenium could hlep me click the the options, and i also record that, the recoders using xpath method to find the element , but now it cannot found it ,

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("(.//*[normalize-space(text()) and normalize-space(.)='DN 80 (3 in.)'])[1]/following::td[5]").click()
```

I know it is wrong , but what should i do to select the different options,

Comment: If I'm reading this right, you want to capture all the text of the options in the drop down list? It looks like that dropdown is in a table format. Do you want to select a specific option? Change the option you're selecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because what you are observing is only looking like option and behaving like option. However it is implemented using `table`, `div`s, `CSS` and `JavaScript`. So that you have to deal with those options like with regular `WebElement`s.

Comment: yes, you got the point, then I use official selenium IDE found the right element , thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can make the xpath dynamic my changing the "digit" value as required. Please try the below xpath.

```
"//td[@class='chDigit']//a[contains(text(),'DN '" + digit + ")]/parent::div/parent::td"
```

Comment: Thanks for your comments, then I use the selenium IDE and found the right element .chRow:nth-child(4) .chC2p , I believe you know what  code means, anyway, your advice gives me the right direction